# Possible to render true HDR from Unity URP on supporting display?

Tags: unity, hdr, unity-urp

Can the Unity URP actually output an HDR signal to a supporting monitor?

I don't mean HDR values with tone mapping applied to map the values to an SDR signal, but actual HDR values displayed on the monitor.

Currently it is clamping the values and I can visually see they are dimmer when compared to an HDR image on the same screen.

If it is possible, is it also possible to render HDR on a supporting iphone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When tempted to ask "does [engine] support [feature]", it pays to do a quick search first.

[Let's type "unity hdr output" into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+hdr+output&ia=web). The very first result is [Unity - Manual: High Dynamic Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HDR.html), which says:

> ## Render pipeline compatibility
>
> For information about support for HDR Rendering and HDR Output in the Scriptable Render Pipelines
> URP and HDRP, see the [Render pipeline feature comparison](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/render-pipelines-feature-comparison.html).

And clicking that link takes us to a table showing:

> ## Color
>
> **HDR**
>
> | Feature | Built-in Render Pipeline | URP | HDRP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | HDR rendering | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | HDR output | No | No | Yes |

So there's your answer: no it is not possible to send HDR colour output from the Universal Render Pipeline. Found in one search and two clicks. Try doing this search yourself next time to find your answers faster.